# App just opens and closes after running from android studio on android phone.

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, debugging

App just opens and closes after running from android studio on android phone.

Following warning is also shown :

The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.

I tried making making the app from a tutorial, the app is compiled successfully but just opens and closes when it is  run on android phone.

I have also added log error from log cat.

build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.hp.chatapp"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
versionCode 1
versionName "1.0"
testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

//add library
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'

implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.2'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Main activity is

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE= 1;
private FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
RelativeLayout activity_main;
FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.menu_sign_out){
        AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this).addOnCompleteListener(new 
 OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
              Snackbar.make(activity_main,"You have been signed out.",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              finish();
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode==RESULT_OK){
        Snackbar.make(activity_main,"Successfully signed in.Welcome !",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        displayChatMessage();
    }
    else {
        Snackbar.make(activity_main,"We couldn't sign you in.Please try again later",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    activity_main=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    fab=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText input= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().push().setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail()));
            input.setText("");
        }
    });

//check if not sign in then navigate signin page
if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()==null)
{
    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder().build(),SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE);
  }
  else {
    Snackbar.make(activity_main,"Welcome "+FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail(),Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

//load content
    displayChatMessage();
}

private void displayChatMessage() {
    ListView listOfMessage=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);
    //Suppose you want to retrieve "chats" in your Firebase DB:
    Query query = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats");
//The error said the constructor expected FirebaseListOptions - here you create them:
    FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
            .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
            .setLayout(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1)
            .build();
    //Finally you pass them to the constructor here:
    adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options){
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
            // Get references to the views of message.xml
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
            TextView messageUser=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.message_user);
            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
            messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",model.getMessageTime()));
        }
    };
listOfMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
}

}
```

**EDITED**

log error from logcat

```
08-03 02:00:47.736 3199-3199/com.example.hp.chatapp E/HAL: PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.qcom.so
PATH3 /odm/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
08-03 02:00:47.737 3199-3199/com.example.hp.chatapp E/HAL: PATH2 /vendor/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
PATH1 /system/lib64/hw/gralloc.msm8953.so
```

Comment: You have to find `fatal` errors in your logcat. `Fatal` error are the error's that shows  why the application is unfortunately stopped.

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, any new code you've tried, or an explanation of why any posted answers aren't working, will bump it to the top of the active queue.